# Edges which, when removed from a graph, increase the number of connected components

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness

What word is most commonly used in graph theory for edges which, when removed from a graph, increase the number of connected components?

Such edges can be found in polynomial time. Where was such an algorithm proposed originally? Are there different algorithms?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're called [bridges](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_(graph_theory)). According to Wikipedia,

> A linear time algorithm for finding the bridges in a graph was described by Robert Tarjan in 1974.

Comment: As noted in the Wikipedia article, they may also be called "cut-edges".

Comment: In the context of planarity, the term bridge has another meaning, so cut-edge is safer.